# How do I use separate types of gpus (e.g. 1080Ti vs 2080Ti) on the same docker image without needing to re-run `python setup.py develop`?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I'm using a pytorch-based [repository](https://github.com/CVMI-Lab/ST3D/tree/315a2fd60195cbd7e196789223a0bff25ba94b47) where the installation step specifies to run `python setup.py develop` with this [setup.py file](https://github.com/CVMI-Lab/ST3D/blob/315a2fd60195cbd7e196789223a0bff25ba94b47/setup.py). I have been running the repository fine with 1080Ti and 1080 GPUs using a docker image which clones the repo and runs the setup.py script in the build process. The following are files copied from my Dockerfile.

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/CVMI-Lab/ST3D.git
WORKDIR /ST3D
RUN nvidia-smi
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py develop
```

Upon entering the container, I only mount specific folders within the repo as follows:

```
GPU_ID = 0

ENVS="  --env=NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$GPU_ID
        --env=CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$GPU_ID
        --env=NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all"

VOLUMES="       --volume=$DATA_PATH:/ST3D/data
                --volume=$CODE_PATH/pcdet:/ST3D/pcdet
                --volume=$CODE_PATH/tools:/ST3D/tools
                --volume=$CODE_PATH/output:/ST3D/output"

docker  run -d -it --rm \
        $VOLUMES \
        $ENVS \
        --runtime=nvidia \
        --gpus $GPU_ID \
        --privileged \
        --net=host \
        --workdir=/ST3D \
        darrenjkt/st3d:v0.3.0
```

Recently we installed a 2080Ti in the same computer. When I enter the same docker container with solely the 2080Ti gpu, using the same python script, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

This error pertains to one of the cpp modules installed in the setup.py.

I can solve this by running `python setup.py develop` again which would then enable it to work with the 2080Ti. I've tried then committing the docker container to a 2080Ti specific docker image, and the 1080 docker container to a 1080 specific image. However I noticed that once I run `python setup.py develop` on the 2080Ti container, it then gives me the CUDA error for the 1080 images. And if I run the setup.py on the 1080 gpu again, it'll then give me the CUDA error back on that 2080Ti image. This baffles me as I have not mounted the build files but rather kept them solely in the container and committed it to a new image.

So my question is, how can I set up my environment/docker image such that it doesn't require a rebuild of setup.py each time?

Comment: add arguments to build for the GPUs you need to support: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cpp_extension.html

Comment: Oh that was it! Thank you. I added `RUN TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="6.1 7.5" python setup.py develop` to my Dockerfile and it managed to run on both GPUs. 

"By default the extension will be compiled to run on all archs of the cards visible during the building process of the extension, plus PTX" According to this sentence on the doc link you sent however, I thought the extension would find the archs by itself and hence I didn't think a need to overwrite it.

Comment: I think the torch build system (tries to) autodetect(s) the build settings based on the installed GPU if you don't explicitly list a set of GPU architectures to build.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by building the docker image with the following:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/CVMI-Lab/ST3D.git
WORKDIR /ST3D
RUN nvidia-smi
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="6.1 7.5" python setup.py develop
```

Where the `TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="6.1 7.5"` where it's 6.1 for 1080/1080Ti and 7.5 for 2080Ti. This overwrites the default cpp_extension behaviour to explicitly specify which compute_capability to support.